# Does Netbeans version 6.9.1 support SOA plugin?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, bpel

I need to create a BPEL project but I can't find SOA plugin to install it. Can someone tell how can I add SOA plugin to my Netbeans version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [a NetBeans Formus post via a mailing list](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic20817.html) it appears that the short answer is no.

It appears that the last version of NetBeans that supported the Sun-distributed SOA plugin was NetBeans 6.5, with dubious support on 6.7.

Comment: I read it before posting this question in stackOVerflow but I thought might somebody find somewhat to fix it.

Comment: :) I searched a bit wider and still found nothing. Sun aparently just didn't have enough staff to maintain it. Alas, under Oracle that situation is not likely to change for the better.

Comment: Glassfish apparently had something called Open-ESB that people were being pointed to. The URL for it that I've found seems to be dead--or at least having trouble today.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle appears to be killing off competitors to their SOA Suite 11g.  Unfortunate because NetBeans was oh-so-nice, and I have had only painful and awkward experiences with JDeveloper.  I was just looking for an alternative SCA tool to SOA Suite in NetBeans and it seems that links to any NetBeans/Glassfish related Service Component Architecture type software have been methodically removed.

Comment: do u find the alternative SCA tool or not yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
1. Netbeans 6.X > 6.5 install normally.
2. Go to "Tools -> Plugins" to create a new "Update Center"
3. Click on "Add" and enter the URL: http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.8/uc/m1/dev/catalog.xml.
```